# How to create related table records through a modal form?

Tags: javascript, cakephp, modal-dialog

I have been stuck in this for about four days now and have tried many examples from many other threads but none of them either work for me or adapt to my situation.

Database tables:

**tallyin**

```
id | date | field1 | field2 | field3 | ...other fields
```

**tallyinitems**

```
id | tallyin_id (fk) | name | make | model | description | ...other fields
```

I have a form which is working fine so far which creates the record in table `tallyin`.  The thing is that I need to allow the user to create many items in the `tallyinitems` table at same time the `tallyin` record is saved.  I need the user to be able to click on an ADD button or link that would open a modal form with the form that would create a `tallyinitem` record.  After the item has been saved and the modal form closed, the main form should automatically update the contents of all items being added.

I have tried this using a bunch of separate approaches but so far none has worked right.

I am using `jQuery`, `JQuery UI`, and I added `Prototype` and `Scriptaculous` to attempt the modal form thing and have only accomplished partial results.

I am willing to change prototype or scriptaculous if anybody knows of a better/easier way to make this work.

I cannot understand why aren't there more examples related to this since I would think this is a pretty common scenario for any database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you already knows how to create a modal dialog then all you have to do is pass to the dialog the `id` of the `tallyin` and pass the data to the `tallyinItemsController`. (PS qhy don't you use cake conventions? should be tallyins - whatever they are - and the table for the itemls should be tallyin_items)

Comment: It is a typo.  The table name is in fact tallyins.  I will check your other comments and will let you know.

Comment: The truth regarding the modal part is that at some point it worked but it was a real pain since I was testing different examples from different people and even though like I said, at some point it worked, I would like to know a standard way to create one.  

Would you be so kind and provide an example or a link to a known good tutorial on how to create the modal form?  I am guessing the way to pass the variables is with the Set method but if it is done some other way,  could you please illustrate?

Comment: Also, the modal I created did not cleanly closed to show the original form behind but opened an entirely new blank page with the redirected page containing the index view.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you eant to obtain

Anyway I will do the following (using jquery UI)

Step 1: In your view create a hidden form (see this [example](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form))

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add an Item">
<?php
    $echo $this->Form->create('TallyinItem')
    $echo $this->Form->input( ... ) //other inputs you need for your form
    echo $this->Js->submit(
        'Save', 
        array(
            'complete' => "
                $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
             ", 
            'url' => array(
                'controller' => 'tallyin_items', 
                'action' => 'addToTallyin',
                $tallyin_id // put here the id 
                            // of the tallyin you are 
                            // adding an item to
            )
        )
     );
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
</div>
```

Step 2: add the javascript to enable the dialog

```
$this->Js->buffer('
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true
    });');
```

Step 3: create a button somewhere in your view that open the dialog and stick a js event on it

```
<button id="add-item">Add an item</button>
<?php
    $this->Js->buffer('
        $( "#add-item" )
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
    ');
?>
```

Step 4: create your action in your `TallyinItemsController`

```
public function addToTallyin($tallyin_id)
{
    \\save your data
}
```

there are other actions you could do (validate your data, check if data have been saved an so on...) but this should be working just to begin.

PS I did not test the code above, surely there are a lot o typos, check it twice.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this soon and let you know.

Comment: I have just tried the modal form with the example given and although I am only trying without loading content via Ajax  and actually saving data, so far it is coming out fine.  Thank you for your efforts and will let you know how everything turned out at the end.